# Getting a #name error when running function

Tags: excel, vba

The function is as follow-

```vb
Public Function Discount(Quantity, Price)
If Quantity > 10 Then
Discount = Price * Quantity * 0.15
Else
Discount = 0
End If
End Function
```

I have enabled macro also but i keep getting this error while trying to run this Discount function on
my worksheet

I tried to enable trust access to VBA project under macro setting,
I also made the function public
But i am still unable to use this VB function

Comment: Do you keep the code in a `Module`? Clicking `Insert > Module` will insert a new module in VBA project.

Comment: This example from MS uses almost the same code https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

Comment: If you have a recent Excel version, you can use LAMBDA's to create and store trivial functions like this. eg define a new Name (from the Formula menu) to your sheet called `Discount` and in the "Refers to" type `=LAMBDA(q,p,IF(q>10,p*q*0.15,0))`. You sheet will now have this function available. The main benefit is that you don't use VBA and so don't need a macro-enabled sheet. This may be an alternative depending on your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified VBA code for the Discount example.

```
Option Explicit ' See Note 1

Public Function udfTotalDiscountAmount(lngQuantity As Long, mnyPrice As Long) As LongLong ' See Notes 2, 3 and 4
    If lngQuantity > 10 Then
        udfTotalDiscountAmount = mnyPrice * lngQuantity * 0.15
    Else
        udfTotalDiscountAmount = 0
    End If
End Function

Sub sbTest()
 MsgBox udfTotalDiscountAmount(80, 10)
End Sub
```

**1. How to turn on `Option Explicit` by default for all new VBA Code modules**

Developer > Visual Basic > Insert > Module > Tools > Options > Require variable declaration

Tick the box

OK

**2. How to write a Hello World program from scratch using Excel VBA**

Open Excel > Blank Workbook > File > Options > Customise the Ribbon > Main Tab > Developer > OK > Developer > Visual Basic > Insert > Module

```
  Sub sbHelloWorld()
    MsgBox "HelloWorld"
  End Sub
```

Run > Reset > File > Save

Filename: xl_HW

Save as type: Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)

Save > Run > Run Sub

**3. What is the best data type for money?**

In a database, to store money amounts, the best choice is to use DECIMAL data type or integer type. Float data type is not a good choice for money amounts. It gives some rounding errors because not all floating point numbers have a binary representation.

How do you declare a decimal variable in VBA?

At this time, the Decimal data type can only be used within a Variant; that is, you cannot declare a variable to be of type Decimal. You can, however, create a Variant whose subtype is Decimal by using the CDec function.

[Decimal Data Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/decimal-data-type)

**4. Use a naming convention when writing VBA code**, for example -

Use an obvious name for the function such as `udfTotalDiscountAmount`
for strings prefix s - `sMessage`
for integers prefix i - `iDiscount`

Use a three character prefix to make things clearer, for example for money prefix mny - `mnyPrice`

**5. The Discount function can be represented as a LAMBDA function**

Formulas > Name Manager > New

[image: The Name Manager is used to create a LAMBDA function]

[LAMBDA function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60688&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

**6. Trust Center Settings**

File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings

Macro Settings > Disable VBA Macros with Notification

Message Bar > Show the Message Bar in all applications when active content, such as Active X controls and macros, has been blocked.

This answer was inspired by this example of
[Excel VBA User Defined Functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f)